# Sonarr and Mono install

Tags: apt, updates, mono

Trying to install sonarr and most guides I find state need to install Mono. But all the guides seem to use the cmd

echo “**deb** http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main” | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
“**deb** http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main”

Whenever **deb** is thrown in there I start getting errors when trying to install other programs:

E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I am a Linux noob, running ubuntu 16.04.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bad idea to follow guides  by rote - this isn't a magic spell. Mono has been in the Ubuntu repositories for many years, so there should be no reason to add a Debian repo. Debian wheezy is very old. Remove the Debian repo from your sources.

Comment: I've found that out the hard way a few times! However this was from the mono page for 16.04     http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/. As a noob what's the best way to remove the Debian repo?

Comment: You can keep the mono repo if you wish...but *they* must provide support for the resulting errors. The easiest way to remove a source (like a non-Ubuntu repo) is using your Software & Updates control panel (do a Search for it).